# How to change visibility of TMenuItem in c++ builder?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder to develop an application.
I want to iterate through all the TMenuItems inside my MainMenu, because I want to change the caption of some of them.
I used this code:

```
 int numAction = MainMenu1->Items->Count;
 for (int i=0;i<numAction;i++)
 {
        TMenuItem* tmpAction = &MainMenu1->Items[i];
        tmpAction->Caption = "Test Caption";
 }
```

I think it should work, but I always get a crash of the application. With this kind of message:

> *Debugger Exception Notification Project Project1.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message Access violation at address
>   501C380E in module vcl120.bpl.  Read of address 0000003C.*

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `MainMenu1->Items->Items[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TMenu` has a property of type

```
_property TMenuItem* Items
```

which in turns has a property of array type

```
__property TMenuItem* Items[int Index]
```

So, the solution is (as n.m. already noticed) to write

```
TMenuItem* tmpAction = MainMenu1->Items->Items[i];
```

Comment: Alternatively, `TMenuItem` has a `operator[]` in C++, which is what Tirma was probably trying to call originally. The correct syntax for calling that operator is `TMenuItem* tmpAction = (*(MainMenu1->Items))[i];` Not quite as elegant as just calling `MainMenu1->Items->Items[]` instead.